# How do I show how many users are on a page with pusher

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, pusher

I am trying to set up online classrooms with a max of two people in the room... still I wan't the teacher to see when he is connected and when the student is connected.

I am trying toget the number of users connected using Pushers members.me function but I am getting the error that says...

> members is undefined

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
    /**
     *
     */
    var pusher = {
        /**
         *
         */
        init: function(){
            this.p = new Pusher('12345678910', {
                cluster: 'eu',
                authEndpoint: '<?php echo base_url('websockets/auth'); ?>',
                //   encrypted: true
            });

            // channels
            this.channel1 = this.p.subscribe('private-messages');
            this.channel2 = this.p.subscribe('private-slides');

            // binding channels to events
            this.channel1.bind('client-message-triggered', function(data){
                chatbox.showMessage(data);
            });
            this.channel2.bind('client-slide-triggered', function(data){
                users = pusher.channel2.members.me;
                console.log(users);
                slider.showCard(data.card_id);
            });
        },
    }
    pusher.init();
```

**Q:**

How can I get the number of users using the channels (for example channel2 above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to be using presence channels instead of private channels. You can find out more about them here: https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_presence_channels

The short summary though is that your channel should instead be called `presence-slides`.

Comment: Thanks! Answered my question.